# I need to automate the filling of a HTML form in a web browser, how?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, pyautogui

I am trying to build a python script that captures my screen (a website will be opened), finds the coordinates of a text entry box on the displayed web site, and then clicks in that text entry box.

I am wondering how to achieve this.

I considered PyAutoGUI and OpenCV.

The text box I need to locate:
[image]

The example web site to find it in:
[image]

Comment: use selenium for your automation tasks. use pyautogui, which does the "image finding". https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-locate-functions

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75114471/moving-mouse-on-the-screen-to-an-image-location-using-cv2-matchtemplate-pyth

Answer (score 1):

You can use the cv2.matchTemplate() function to match a template image (the image you want to find) with the live feed from your screen. The function returns a "result" image, which you can then use to find the location of the match using the cv2.minMaxLoc() function. Once you have the location of the match, you can extract the x and y coordinates and pass them to pyautogui.click() to simulate a mouse click at that location.

Comment: pyautogui uses matchTemplate, just use pyautogui https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-locate-functions